# How to Read a remote certificate store with .Net

Tags: c#, security, encryption, openssl

Reading from a remote certificate store with .Net

I've Tried this but no success

```
X509Store storex = new X509Store(@"\\AA-LAP-111\MY",StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
storex.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
```

Note :  `\\AA-LAP-111\MY` is Colleague machine
Please advise.

Comment: X509Store only functions locally, hence *LocalMachine*, you would need to p/invoke CertOpenStore or use CAPICOM, many examples if you google.

Comment: @Alex K Thanks Alex for you valuable advise,I implemented code shown here storeHandle = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,@"\\AA-LAP-001\My"); I am trying to access remote machine.it works fine with my Local machine .Please advise